# PHP (and SQL) how to get given record

Tags: php, sql

I have Data base "players" with:

```
id Name gold
1 joe 50
2 tom 40
3 jzd 70
```

I use a PHP to get info from base to variable:

```
$base = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM Players");
$data = $base->fetch_assoc();
```

When i use

```
$data['name'];
```

I get only a name FIRST id, how to get name for example id 2 or 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return the record for a specific user use

```
SELECT * FROM players WHERE id = <id>;
```

If you want to list all the players returned from your first query (select all, no where statement), you need to loop through the array returned from doing your query. Use a foreach (here are [some examples](https://gist.github.com/odan/0c3f80eec13ac493ed64fadd0bb1a66e)